# Finding longest word in string

Tags: c#

Ok, so I know that questions LIKE this have been asked a lot on here, but I can't seem to make solutions work.
I am trying to take a string from a file and find the longest word in that string.
Simples.

I think the issue is down to whether I am calling my methods on a `string[]` or `char[]`, currently `stringOfWords` returns a `char[]`.

I am trying to then order by descending length and get the first value but am getting an `ArgumentNullException` on the `OrderByDescending` method.

Any input much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TextExercises
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\RichardsPC\Documents\TestText.txt");
            var stringOfWords = fileText.ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine("Text in file: " + fileText);
            Console.WriteLine("Words in text: " + fileText.Split(' ').Length);

            // This is where I am trying to solve the problem
            var finalValue = stringOfWords.OrderByDescending(n => n.length).First();

            Console.WriteLine("Largest word is: " + finalValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code you've posted as "This is where I am trying to solve the problem" does not look like C# (as all .Net properties/methods are upper case). That code should be giving you compile errors instead...

Comment: Using var for all your variable declarations makes your code less readable.

Comment: @MrAnderson that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @stuartd the op was implying (before edit) he was unsure whether he is operating on char[] or string[]. var makes it unclear to us on here as well.

Comment: @MrAnderson I am using `var` as the course I am following along with promotes that over 'explicit' typing. Point noted for future posts to aid readability though.

Comment: @RichC var is great in an IDE where you can hover mouse over to see type :)

Comment: @MrAnderson Yeah I'm using VS15, so it's handy here, but easy to forget that it may not be as readable elsewhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `ToArray()` in this case returns `char[]` which is an array of individual characters. But instead you need an array of individual words. You can get it like this:

```
string[] stringOfWords = fileText.Split(' ');
```

And you have a typo in your lambda expression (uppercase L):

```
n => n.Length
```

Comment: @MartinHeralecký, thanks, that was spot on. Creating the string array with the split on whitespace sorted it. And of course the typo there!

Answer (score 4):

## Don't split the string, use a Regex

**If you care about performance** you don't want to split the string. The reason in order to do the split method will have to **traverse the entire string**, **create new strings for the items it finds** to split and **put them into an array**, computational cost of more than `N`, then doing an order by you do another (at least) `O(nLog(n))` steps.

You can use a Regex for this, which will be more efficient, because it will only **iterate over the string once**

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\w+)\s",RegexOptions.Compiled);
var match = regex.Match(fileText);
var currentLargestString = "";

while(match.Success)
{
     if(match.Groups[1].Value.Length>currentLargestString.Length)
     {
         currentLargestString = match.Groups[1].Value;
     }

     match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

The nice thing about this is that you don't need to break the string up all at once to do the analysis and if you need to load the file incrementally is a fairly easy change to just persist the word in an object and call it against multiple strings

## If you're set on using an Array don't order by just iterate over

You don't need to do an order by your just looking for the largest item, computational complexity of order by is in most cases `O(nLog(n))`, iterating over the list has a complexity of `O(n)`

```
var largest = "";
foreach(var item in strArr)
{
    if(item.Length>largest.Length)
        largest = item;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var fileText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\RichardsPC\Documents\TestText.txt");
var words = fileText.Split(' ')
var finalValue = fileText.OrderByDescending(n=> n.Length).First();
Console.WriteLine("Longest word: " + finalValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the other answer, you need to split your string.

```
string[] stringOfWords = fileText.split(new Char [] {',' , ' ' });
//all is well, now let's loop over it and see which is the biggest
int biggest = 0;
int biggestIndex = 0;

for(int i=0; i<stringOfWords.length; i++) {
    if(biggest < stringOfWords[i].length) {
        biggest = stringOfWords[i].length;
        biggestIndex = i;
    }
}
return stringOfWords[i];
```

What we're doing here is splitting the string based on whitespace (' '), or commas- you can add an unlimited number of delimiters there - each word, then, gets its own space in the array.

From there, we're iterating over the array. If we encounter a word that's longer than the current longest word, we update it.

Comment: How is that not the longest word?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more primitive. But it works too...

```
var sentence = "Her sey gecer gider. Hayattir geri kalan falan";
string[] sentences = sentence.Split(' ');

var longest = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i++)
{
    if (i != sentences.Length - 1)
    {
        if (sentences[i].Length > sentences[i + 1].Length)
            longest = sentences[i].Length;
    }
    else if (sentences[i].Length > longest)
    {
        longest = sentences[i].Length;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(longest);
```