# Finding the longest word (and write it out) in string without split, distinct and foreach

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I got an assignment to make a method to find the longest word in a string without split, distinct and foreach.

I was able to split the words and count the length but I am stuck on how can I actually compare and write them out.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String s1 = "Alex has 2 hands.";
    longestWord(s1);
    Console.
}

static void longestWord(String s1)
{
    char emp = ' ';
    int count = 0;
    char[] ee = s1.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ee.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ee[i] == emp || ee[i] == '.')
        {
            count++;
            Console.Write(" " + (count-1));
            Console.WriteLine();
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(ee[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output right now looks like this:

```
Alex 4
has 3
2 1
hands 5
```

I am pretty sure I would be able to get only the longest number to show by comparing **count** before reset with temp int but how to write out the word with it.

Or if there is a easier way which probably is.

Comment: What about Regex or do you want to avoid it as well? It would make stuff a lot simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding longest word in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492145/finding-longest-word-in-string)

Comment: @Twenty actually the last answer there helped a lot (other are split, foreach and regex which we havent talked about so now sure if I can use it). thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already on a good way. Instead of directly printing the words, store the length and position of the longest word and print it at the end. Like so:

```
static void longestWord(String s1)
{
    char emp = ' ';

    int longestLength = 0;
    int longestStart = 0;

    int currentStart = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s1[i] == emp || s1[i] == '.')
        {
            // calculate the current word length
            int currentLength = i - currentStart;

            // test if this is longer than the currently longest
            if(currentLength > longestLength)
            {
                longestLength = currentLength;
                longestStart = currentStart;
            }

            // a new word starts at the next character
            currentStart = i + 1;                     
        }
    }

    // print the longest word
    Console.WriteLine($"Longest word has length {longestLength}: \"{s1.Substring(longestStart, longestLength)}\"");
}
```

There is no need for the `.ToCharArray()`. You can access the string directly.

Comment: This is awesome, I was trying to make it char by char and split/write it that way but this is much easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I will question whether you are actually supposed to treat `"2"` as a word and count it at all. Using [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) will allow you to approach the problem using a LINQ one-liner:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String s1 = "Alex has 2 hands.";
    var word = longestWord(s1);
    Console.WriteLine(word);

    //Console.ReadLine();
}

static string longestWord(string s1) {
    return Regex.Matches(s1,"[A-Za-z]+") // find all sequences containing alphabetical characters, you can add numberas as well: [A-Za-z0-9]
         .Cast<Match>() // cast results to Enumberable<Match> so we can apply LINQ to it
         .OrderByDescending(m => m.Length) // luckily for us, Match comes with Length, so we just sort our results by it
         .Select(m => m.Value) // instead of picking up everything, we only want the actual word
         .First(); // since we ordered by descending - first item will be the longest word
}
```

Comment: We havent talked about regex but I seems like it makes things a lot easier (saw it used a lot) so i will look into it. Thank you!

Comment: @Sukonbu I suppose the point of your exercise was to work through an algorithm rather than rely on libraries. If that is indeed the case you'd be better off with other proposed solutions. I will however point out that Linq version does not explicitly perform split, distinct or foreach per se (although it definitely relies on IEnumerable), so you might be able to hand it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can store for every word the chars in new list of chars (list for dynamic length)
and if the new word is longer of the prev long word convert it to string.
If you have two word in same length it will take the first.
If you want the last change the "maxLength < count" to "maxLength <= count"

```
static string longestWord(String s1)
    {
        char emp = ' ';
        int count = 0;

        int maxLength = 0;
        string maxWord = string.Empty;
        List<char> newWord = new List<char>();

        char[] ee = s1.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ee.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ee[i] == emp || ee[i] == '.')
            {                    
                if (maxLength < count)
                {
                    maxLength = count;
                    maxWord = new string(newWord.ToArray());
                }

                count = 0;
                newWord = new List<char>();
            }
            else
            {
                newWord.Add(ee[i]);
                count++;
            }
        }

        return maxWord;
    }
```

Comment: Havent thought about using List<> will look into it, thank you!